# Magento - Resource not callable

Tags: soap, magento-1.6

**Context**

I tried, many times, to create a Magento module providing a set of custom methods.

I'm using Magento 1.6.2 and followed many tutorials but my last try was using [this web utility - Magento Module Creator](http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/).

In the module configuration I tried using: Milyuncarros (as namespace) and Mobile (as module).
Other stuff like codePool and version are left as default values (local, 0.1.0).

In the option "Need Add Magento API" and added one method: `saleSearchCategories`.

The site itself tells to call the soap methods like: yourmodulename_api.yourmethod (for my case it would be Mobile_Api.saleSearchCategories or mobile_api.salesearchcategories - have issues with both: "Invalid API Path" and "Resource path is not callable" respectively).

Cache Management is disabled for the modules and I ensured the Milyuncarros_Mobile module is enabled.

I also explicitly enabled, after many tries, "RewriteEngine On" in the appache .htaccess at the Magento root (i.e. as a sibling of `/apps`).

**Issue**

When I try to call the soap method I created (with no parameters) I get a SoapFault with "Resource path is not callable".

**Current State**

Generated file structure are as follows:

app/etc/modules/Milyuncarros_Mobile.xml (auto generated):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Milyuncarros_Mobile>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>            
      <depends>
        <Mage_Api />
      </depends>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Milyuncarros_Mobile>
  </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Milyuncarros/Mobile/Model/Api.php (Autogenerated + Edited):

```
<?php

class Milyuncarros_Mobile_Model_Api extends Mage_Api_Model_Resource_Abstract
{        
    public function saleSearchCategories()
    {
        //everything was generated but the following line
        return array('active' => true);
    }
}
```

app/code/local/Milyuncarros/Mobile/Helper/Data.php (Autogenerated):

```
<?php

class Milyuncarros_Mobile_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

app/code/local/Milyuncarros/Mobile/etc/api.xml (Autogenerated):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <api>
    <resources>
      <mobile_api translate="title" module="mobile">
        <title>Myapi</title>
        <acl>mobile/api</acl>
        <model>mobile/api</model>
        <methods>
          <salesearchcategories translate="title" module="mobile">
            <title>Categories listed as public sale searchable</title>
            <acl>mobile/salesearchcategories</acl>
          </salesearchcategories>
        </methods>
      </mobile_api>
    </resources>
    <acl>
      <resources>
        <mobile translate="title" module="mobile">
          <title>Mobile</title>
          <sort_order>2000</sort_order>                    
          <salesearchcategories translate="title" module="mobile">
            <title>Categories listed as public sale searchable</title>
          </salesearchcategories>
        </mobile>
      </resources>
    </acl>
  </api>
</config>
```

(I tried `mobile_api`.`salesearchcategories` based on this spec).

And finally -but not least important- the module config file:
app/code/local/Milyuncarros/Mobile/etc/config.xml (Autogenerated):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Milyuncarros_Mobile>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Milyuncarros_Mobile>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <mobile>
        <class>Milyuncarros_Mobile_Helper</class>
      </mobile>
    </helpers>
    <models>
      <mobile>
        <class>Milyuncarros_Mobile_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>mobile_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </mobile>
    </models>
  </global>
</config>
```

**Question**: When I Try to call mobile_api.salesearchcategories I get an error:

SoapFault: Resource path is not callable.

What must I do to stop getting that error? The documentation tells few to nothing about (or it's too tricky to be searched in, and I did not find it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. The module was well-formatted (since I used a well-known generator for that).

What I did is:

1. Edit the generated Helper_Data class to extend from Mage_Core_Helper_Data instead of _Abstract.
2. Refresh the cache (Cache Management) and refreshing the compilation (Tools > Compilation).
3. (I don't know if it was relevant) I entered to the admin role for SOAP and saved again the role.

Then it worked: I could reach my entry point using mobile_api.salesearchcategories.

Comment: in system.log have this error: include(): Failed opening 'Mage\Webservice\Model\Api.php' for inclusion